# LUA options to fetch variables from another file (Global variables vs Modules)

Tags: lua, lua-table

Please help in understanding the difference in terms of best practices from option 1 and 2.

All I need is to access is, variables from file a.lua in b.lua

I have two files a.lua and b.lua:

---

Option 1: (I am accessing a global variable from a.lua in b.lua)(This is working)

a.lua

```
name = "hello world"
```

b.lua

```
require("a")

print(name)
```

---

Option 2: (This is also working fine)

a.lua

```
local config = {}

config.name = "hello world"

return config
```

b.lua

```
local config = require("a")

print(config.name)
```

In both options above, I am able to fetch variable name, from a.lua in b.lua. 
Please help to understand which option is better.

Thanks for your help on this.

Regards...

Comment: Some at least minimal effort regarding formatting would be appreciated by anyone who might answer your question - see [help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 does not write to the global environment, which is a good thing if you're writing a library for others to use.

If you're writing something just for yourself, both options are good.

Nevertheless, if you're using option 1 for config files, then option 2 is useful, even in the case, because it is easier to save the config by traversing a small table than by traversing the whole global environment (which is also a table, of course).